# Tab Bar not appearing on applicationDidBecomeActive

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

Requirement - When user open Application from the background tabBar selected index should be 2

What i tried -

```
//For getting current visible controller -
    public extension UIWindow {
        public var visibleViewController: UIViewController? {
            return UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(self.rootViewController)
        }

        public static func getVisibleViewControllerFrom(_ vc: UIViewController?) -> UIViewController? {
            if let nc = vc as? UINavigationController {
                return UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(nc.visibleViewController)
            } else if let tc = vc as? UITabBarController {
                return UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(tc.selectedViewController)
            } else {
                if let pvc = vc?.presentedViewController {
                    return UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(pvc)
                } else {
                    return vc
                }
            }
        }
    }
let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    //Selected 2 tabbar -
         func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
                if appdelegate.window?.visibleViewController != nil {
                    appdelegate.window?.visibleViewController?.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false
                    appdelegate.window?.visibleViewController?.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)

                    appdelegate.window?.visibleViewController?.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
                    appdelegate.window?.visibleViewController?.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
                    appdelegate.window?.bringSubview(toFront: (appdelegate.window?.visibleViewController?.tabBarController?.view)!)

                }
            }
```

The code is working fine but problem is Tabbbar get hidden. Why?

Comment: Is the tabBar always the Root ??

Comment: @Sh_Khan Yes...

Answer (score 0):

This will work if each tab has a navigationController

```
if let tabController = self.window!.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
         if let navController =  tabBarController.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController{
              navController.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
              tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to subclass `UITabBarViewController`
2. override `viewWillAppear` method.
3. Subscrib `UIApplicationWillEnterForeground` notification.
4. Set selectedIndex on notification received.

   ```
   class HomeViewController: UITabBarController {
   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewWillAppear(animated)
       NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(applicationWillEnterForeground(notification:)), name: .UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)
   }

   override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewWillAppear(animated)
       NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)
   }

   @objc private func applicationWillEnterForeground(notification: Notification) {
       selectedIndex = 2
   }}
   ```